# iOS constraints broken on emulator for labels

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

I am building a notes app for iOS on xCode. In the storyboard I have a table view > table cell > content view; and then inside the content view I have three labels. I'm running into problems constraining the labels correctly, everything else displays just fine.

I have tried the suggested constraints, and I have tried my own for a number of hours. It looks fine in the Storyboard and the constraints are on all sides. There should be spacing between the labels, but when I run it in the emulator it is like it ignores my constraints and decides to do its own thing, which is stack all the labels up in the upper left hand corner on top of eachother. What can I do. I have included a couple screenshots as well as a snippet from the source code for the storyboard. I essentially just want the title on top, and beneath it the label for the author, and beneath that the text. I don't understand what is happening.

[This is what the Storyboard looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH9Pd.png)

[This is how it looks like on the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35F1z.png)

```xml
<tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="NoteCell" rowHeight="190" id="Qv2-eK-dm0" customClass="NoteCell" customModule="Notes" customModuleProvider="target">
  <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="414" height="190"/>
  <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
  <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="Qv2-eK-dm0" id="sEv-Pt-p6x" customClass="NoteCell" customModule="Notes" customModuleProvider="target">
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="189.5"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
    <subviews>
      <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" text="Creator" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="y5w-xk-OZf">
        <rect key="frame" x="20" y="40" width="58" height="21"/>
        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
        <nil key="textColor"/>
        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
      </label>
      <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" misplaced="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" text="Title" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cMo-l6-r6s">
        <rect key="frame" x="20" y="11" width="34" height="21"/>
        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
        <nil key="textColor"/>
        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
      </label>
      <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="center" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" text="Text" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6sK-TM-dgw">
        <rect key="frame" x="20" y="100" width="33" height="21"/>
        <constraints>
          <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="33" id="HrI-90-tNn"/>
        </constraints>
        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
        <nil key="textColor"/>
        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
      </label>
    </subviews>
    <constraints>
      <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="6sK-TM-dgw" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="58" id="1hq-R0-otf"/>
      <constraint firstItem="y5w-xk-OZf" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6sK-TM-dgw" secondAttribute="leading" id="FnH-oM-aQv"/>
      <constraint firstItem="cMo-l6-r6s" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6sK-TM-dgw" secondAttribute="centerX" id="It8-Lz-hKc"/>
      <constraint firstItem="cMo-l6-r6s" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="sEv-Pt-p6x" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="SAm-ft-qJF"/>
      <constraint firstItem="cMo-l6-r6s" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="y5w-xk-OZf" secondAttribute="leading" id="To4-Bj-4dn"/>
      <constraint firstItem="y5w-xk-OZf" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="cMo-l6-r6s" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="ZjD-2T-R1j"/>
      <constraint firstItem="6sK-TM-dgw" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y5w-xk-OZf" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="39" id="tcE-3w-0IZ"/>
    </constraints>
  </tableViewCellContentView>
  <connections>
    <outlet property="authorLabel" destination="y5w-xk-OZf" id="emS-as-uYG"/>
    <outlet property="noteTextLabel" destination="6sK-TM-dgw" id="Q92-6x-4a0"/>
    <outlet property="textLabel" destination="6sK-TM-dgw" id="M9B-cr-q2V"/>
    <outlet property="titleLabel" destination="cMo-l6-r6s" id="WLz-mK-Hgj"/>
  </connections>
</tableViewCell>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Title label add Top, Leading and Trailing constraints with the superview(Content view). The Title label constraints would be like this in the below screen shot : [image]

For Author label, add Leading and Trailing constraints with the superview(Content view) and Top space to Title label as shown here :

[image]

For Details text label add Leading and Trailing constraints with the superview(Content view) and Top space to Author label as shown here :

[image]

Here I have assumed that all the labels would be fixed so all of them have the fixed height constraints and I have also given some colours to show the difference. The output would look something like this :

[image]

Hope this would help you.

Comment: I did this, all the things you said above just now and it still smashes up all the text into the top left corner, at least when you click on it. The text is in the right place, but oddly not colored right, and creator is not to be seen at all.  https://i.imgur.com/4WKZVQp.png

Comment: Check the top constraint for the Creator label. It should be referenced to the Title Label not the superview of the creator label. Below is great reference to get deep knowledge about the auto layout.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/443-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started